# A suitable tool to simulate vision based robotic grasping?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing some work concerning recognition of grasping points using 2-D image information and camera calibration information.I just want to verify my recognition method. Is there any simulation tool to help me focus on the verification of my recognition work? I hope to get different objects' image information easily and if I give a grasping hypotheses the motion planning work could be finished by the simulator.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66265/a-suitable-tool-to-simulate-vision-based--robotic-grasping-?/) by [kgl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5286/kgl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best one I've seen is GraspIt, developed by Columbia:  https://graspit-simulator.github.io/

You can test multiple objects with different grasping points. Like in the picture here:

[image: image description]

It has ROS integration so that's a plus :)

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0